# ouputing an array from MySQL db...how to remove square brackets and double quotes in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I am trying to retrieve an array from a mySQL db and print the output to the screen.

The array is encoded prior to writing to the db with the following:

`$itemsarray = json_encode($items);`

It is then INSERTed into the db with the following query:

`mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO pages (email, date, items, title, url, expiry) VALUES ('$email', '$timestamp', '$itemsarray', '$title', '$new_url', '$expiry')")`

When I retrieve the value for $itemsarray onto the screen, the output appears like this:  `["forks","knives","spoons","plates","cups","mugs","napkins"]`.

I'm familiar with PHP and relatively new to actually writing any MySQL queries so it took me a while to just get it written and returned, so please be easy on me here. :)

Do I need to write a function of some sort that strips out the " " and [ ], or do I need some further arguments within my JSON function?

Comment: [json_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) what you read from the db to convert it back to an array.... though it would probably be better if you wrote the items to a separate table (normalized your database) than storing it like this

Comment: Thanks Mark.  I tried the json_decode() function and just got 'Array' as an output.  I completely agree with you on having it in a separate table, but I don't have the skills to go down that road yet, unfortunately.

Comment: You don't `echo` arrays, otherwise you get `'Array'` as your output; either loop through the array echoing each entry, or implode it to a string and echo that

Comment: Thanks again.  I didn't know that, but won't forget it now.  I took your advice and imploded the array into a string for output.

Answer (score 0):

Per @Mark Baker 's recommendation, this is what worked:

```
$items_list = $row['items'];
$list = json_decode($items_list);
$comma_separated = implode(", ", $list);
echo $comma_separated;
```

It outputs something like this:

```
List Contents: forks, knives, spoons, plates, cups, mugs, napkins
```

Thanks Mark!